# Join 2 Queries and a Pivot in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression

I have 2 queries that I want to join together. They come from the same table, but the organization and structure of columns is bad. Hence the need for a Pivot in Query 1, then join it to Query 2.

I do know that this needs to be done with a CTE, but my output either results in a blank query, or info in the wrong columns.

I'm using SSMS18. Thanks for the help.

Query 1

```
Select *, '' AS 'DNC', '' AS 'DNF', '' AS 'DNR' from 

(Select 
    Opin, 
    Qty,
    [TicketDate],
    [TicketNumber],
    [Cust],
    [ProdID]
from [dbo].[obser]) AS  ID

Pivot (
    SUM([Qty])
    For [Opin] IN ([ArvUnits],[DeliveryUnits])

    ) AS SingleOTRow

    where 
    
    TicketDate between  '2021-01-01' and '2021-03-15'
    and ProdID  like '%_LB%'
```

Query 2

```
    select
IOA.Cust, IOA.TicketNumber, IOA.TicketDate, '' AS 'ProdID','' AS 'IOA QTY', '' AS 'Delivery Units', IOA.ProdID AS 'DNC',
case
When IOA.Qty >=1 Then '1'
else 'N'
end AS 'DNF',

CASE
when IOA.ProdID = '21' Then 'Full'
else 'Not a Valid DNC- Review'
END as 'DNR'

from [dbo].[obser] AS IOA

where 
IOA.TicketDate between '2021-01-01' and '2021-03-15' and
IOA.Opin= 'DNS'
```

Sample Data

[Sample Data][image: 1]

Comment: Please post the sample data and expected output. Also create table syntax when posting questions like these.

Comment: Please mention the dbms you are using with version. And some sample data with desired output will be great.

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Also note that the version of SSMS is largely irrelevant as SSMS is purely a client UI for SQL Server. What is more useful is `select @@version`.